# Form isn't sending

Tags: php, forms

I'm staging a site for a client and I'm trying to create a form from scratch rather than use a plugin.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The page keeps refreshing to the homepage and no email gets sent.

Could someone please point out in my code where I've gone wrong...

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From: Test'; 
        $to = 'email@example.com'; 
        $subject = 'Hello';

        if ($name == "" OR $email == "") {
            echo "You must specify a value for name, email address, and message.";
            exit;
        }

        foreach( $_POST as $value ){
                if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
                    echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";
                    exit;
                }
        }

        require_once("assets/inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        if (!$mail->ValidateAddress($email)){
            echo "You must specify a valid email address.";
        }

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        header("Location: http://natashamcdiarmid.com/clients/JLP/wp/contact/?status=thanks");
        exit;
    }
?>




<?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
    <p>Thanks, I'll get back to your shortly!</p>
<?php } else ?>

<form method="post" action="contact">

    <p><label>Name</label></p>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

    <p><label>Email</label></p>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    <p><label>Message</label></p>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

    <p><label>*What is 2+2?</label></p>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

    <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>

    <?php
        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            }
        }
    ?>

</form>
```

Comment: If things don't work as expected: what does the development console in your browser say? That is where you should see an error explaining what the problem is...

Comment: Sorry I'm bit of a newbie. I use the developer console for editing css but never for seeing issues. Could you please expand?

Answer (score 0):

The form that you are posting to isn't much of a directory.

```
<form method="post" action="contact">  
 should it be contact.php?
```

this action should be the directory of your form handler

Comment: I'm working in a WordPress environment so I figured it had to follow the clean url's of that. Contact.php doesn't work. All of the information is listed at the top of my contact page. It's all loading from one area.

Answer (score 0):

A major issue with WordPress that always gets me is that it uses some request variables with common names, and messing with them causes unpredictable errors. For instance, the `name` parameter is used to locate and display the current post or web page.

Try renaming your `name` field to something else, like `your_name`.

When I create forms for use in WordPress, typically I prefix every field with something custom, like `acme_contact_name`, `acme_contact_email`, etc. A little more typing, but safer.

Comment: @M Miller Thanks, but I wound up using a plugin because I couldn't resolve the issue.